# why does textbox.disabled= true clears the text of the textbox?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a few asp:Textbox elements in my code, which I was disabling with javascript after the user clicks validate.

eg:

```
 <asp:TextBox CssClass="dateClass" ID="fromDateE" width="100px" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

My javascript function was :

```
function disableDateFields()
{
    var dates = document.getElementsByClassName("dateClass");
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) 
    {
        //console.log(dates[i]);
        dates[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

The problem I had was after submit the value I had inside the textbox was getting cleared.

To get around this problem I changed the JS function so instead of disabling I set the readOnly property of the text box to true :

```
function disableDateFields()
{
    var dates = document.getElementsByClassName("dateClass");

    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) 
    {
        //console.log(dates[i]);
        dates[i].readOnly= true;
    }
}
```

I am just wondering why disabling the textbox clears out the value inside of it?  Is this simply the default behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: If this is a Web Forms application, just set `EnableViewState` to `true` for that element and the value won't go away when the form is submitted.

Comment: Disabling alone does not clear the value, ex: https://jsfiddle.net/pfs2hadt/

Comment: @ScottMarcus it is a web forms application. I am not setting the view states anywhere.. isn't the default true?

Comment: ```document.getElementById("dateClass").disabled = true;```

Comment: I can't remember if it is the default or not, since there is more overhead to using ViewState, I would think it is not on by default.

Comment: @ScottMarcus https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate(v=vs.110).aspx says default is true

Comment: @ScottMarcus actually I tried it with EnableViewState set to true on the textbox.. it still cleared the text inside of the textbox...

Comment: `EnableViewState` must also be on for the page as well as the control.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that didn't work either. I added EnableViewState at page level and at the control level.. <%@ Page Title="test page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="app_Member_testPage" EnableViewState="true" %> and <asp:TextBox ID="fromDateE" width="100px" runat="server" Text="" EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case ViewState has nothing to do with this. The problem lies in the fact that disabled input controls are not part of the Form Post back to the server. But because the TextBox does still exists on the page asp.net will fill it with the values it receives from PostBack, but that one is `null` so the TextBox is made empty.

You can check this with the following snippet. You will see that `fromDateE.UniqueID` does not exists and thus `fromDateE` will be emptied.

```
if (Request.Form[fromDateE.UniqueID] == null)
{
    fromDateE.Text = "Form Post was empty.";
}
```